# Dojox Form/Upload behavior on file selection

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

How can I detect when someone has indeed picked some files from the file explorer and has hit select? I want to add an event on the selection of files.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You have to tie the input form to the onChange method.

```
<input type="file" data-dojo-attach-event="onChange:_onUpload" data-dojo-type="dojox/form.Uploader"/>


_onUpload: function(evt){

}
```